# C++ Windows Sleep() without stopping other tasks

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sleep

I know what I'm asking is contradictory

```
SendNumber(LastNumber);
Sleep(2000+(level*100));
```

SendNumber() is a function that sends LastNumber to an edit control with WM_SETTEXT. What I'm trying to do is sleep the program for a moment, leaving the text on the edit control, and after the time ends remove this text.

My problem is that Sleep() stops WM_SETTEXT from typing the text, so the program waits 2000+(level*100) milliseconds and then the text appears on the edit box.

Is there any way to stop the program from running forward until the time ends, but without stopping all the window activity?

Comment: Timer, threads, ... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and WM_TIMER, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

> UpdateWindow(your_edit_control);

just after SendNumber.

Comment: Thanks. This solution wasn't exactly what's being asked, but it's a good solution and it'll probably solve problems in the future easier

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  This will send your program a WM_TIMER message after a specified period, which you can then handle.

Comment: This one is **much** better than sleeping, since your window isn't getting unresponsive.